# Function that Inserts a node into a linked list sorted

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_MODEL 25
#define MAX_LINE 50
typedef struct car{
    char* model;
    char* color;
    int year;
    struct car* next;
}car;
car* readFromFile(FILE*);
car* insertInSortedOrder(car*, char*, char*, int);
car* createCar(char*, char*, int);
void printCars(car*);

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    //creating a file pointer, opening file
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen(*(argv+1), "r");
    car* head = NULL;

    //this first reads cars from files, puts it into linked list and prints
    head = readFromFile(fptr);
    puts("do we get here");
    printCars(head);
    return 0;
}
///this function reads information from a text file, sends it to insertInSortedOrder function
car* readFromFile(FILE* fptr){

    char *M, *C, *year;
    char *readLine= malloc(sizeof(car)*MAX_MODEL);
    int yr;

    car *head=NULL;
    while(fgets(readLine,MAX_LINE,fptr)!= NULL){
            M = strtok(readLine,"|");
            C = strtok(NULL,"|");
            year = strtok(NULL,"|");
            yr = atoi(year);
            head = insertInSortedOrder(head,M,C,yr);
    }
    return head;
}
//this function sends new info to createCar to put it into a list, gets it and puts it
//into sorted order according to alphabetical order by model
car* insertInSortedOrder(car* head, char* model, char* color, int year){

    //if list is emppty
    if(head == NULL){
            head = createCar(model,color,year);
    }
    else{
            car *new = createCar(model,color,year);
            car *current,*previous;
            current = head;
            previous = NULL;
            puts("here?");
            //compares new car model to next model, if  next is greater than new, move onto next pair
            while(strcmp(new->model,current->model) < 0){
            puts("here2");
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
            puts("here2.5");
            }
            puts("here3");
            //if only one thing in the list
            if(previous->next == NULL){
                    //new car is next on list
                    if(strcmp(previous->model,new->model) > 0){
                            previous->next = new;
                    }
                    //new car goes into top of list
                    else{
                            head = new;
                            head->next = previous;
                    }
            }
            //doing stuff at middle or end
            //if new is greater than current
            else{
          puts("here4");
                    previous->next = new;
                    new->next = current;
            }
    }
    return head;
}
//this function creates a new "node" for the list, returns pointer
car* createCar(char* model, char* color, int year){

    car *newCar = malloc(sizeof(car));
    newCar->color = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_MODEL);
    newCar->model = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_MODEL);

    strcpy(newCar->model,model);
    strcpy(newCar->color,color);
    newCar->year = year;
    newCar->next = NULL;

    return newCar;
 }
//this function prints out all of things in linked list
void printCars(car* head){

    if(head == NULL)
            printf("List is empty\n");

    else{
            printf("The list of cars in inventory are:\n");
            while(head!=NULL){
            printf("%-5d %-25s %-13s",head->year,head->model,head->color);
            printf("\n");
            head = head->next;
            }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this program is to read in a file that has a list of cars with their model name, color name, and year in it.  Once its read in, it will be put into a linked list in ascending order by the type of model of the car. Here is the file being read in:

```
Tesla S|royal|2015|
GMC Yukon|white|2005|
Dodge Charger|lime|2010|
Honda Civic|cobalt|1996|
Nissan Titan|saddlewood|2008|
Chevrolet Silverado|saddlewood|1999|
Ford Focus|lime|2000|
Toyota Tacoma|gunmetal|2009|
Tesla X|black|2016|
Nissan Maxima|white|2013|
Ford Explorer|forest|1996|
Chevrolet Corvette|cherry|1982|
Tesla 3|cherry|2017|
Nissan 370Z|royal|2011|
Ford F150|cherry|2006|
Honda Accord|white|2004|
Mitsubishi Eclipse|black|2002|
Toyota Tundra|cobalt|2017|
Dodge Challenger|lemon|1970|
Chevrolet Camaro|black|1966|
```

After putting "./a.out cars.txt" in the command prompt, the output is

```
here?
here2
here2.5
Segmentation fault
```

Because of my puts statements, I know the seg fault is happening somewhere within my while loop in the "insertInSortedOrder" function.  Any help with getting this function to work will be greatly appreciated, thanks

alright I have changed the insert function to:

```
car* insertInSortedOrder(car* head, char* model, char* color, int year){

    //if list is emppty
    if(head == NULL){
            head = createCar(model,color,year);
    }
    else{
            car *new = createCar(model,color,year);
            car *current,*previous;
            current = head;
            previous = NULL;
            //compares new car model to next model, if  next is greater than new, move onto next pair
            while( strcmp(new->model,current->model)  <  0){
                    //if current is only node in list or end of list
                    if(current->next == NULL){
                            current->next = new;
                            return head;
                    }
                    else{
                            //move forward to compare new
                            previous = current;
                            current = current->next;
                    }
            }
            //when new is greater than current, put new on top of it
            previous = new;
            previous->next = current;
    }
    return head;
}
```

now it prints:

```
The list of cars in inventory are:
2015  Tesla S                   royal
2005  GMC Yukon                 white
2010  Dodge Charger             lime 
1999  Chevrolet Silverado       saddlewood
1982  Chevrolet Corvette        cherry
1966  Chevrolet Camaro          black
```

So yay! No more seg fault, but now I think I just have not good algorithm

Comment: 1) `char *readLine= malloc(sizeof(car)*MAX_MODEL);` --> `char *readLine= malloc(sizeof(car)*MAX_LINE);`

Comment: 2) `while(strcmp(new->model, current->model) < 0){
 previous = current;
 current = current->next; }` : at 2nd time in loop `current` is `NULL`. So `NULL->model` occurs seg-fault.

Comment: still same error, I dont think theres a problem reading in the information because I put a printf int he creatCar function to print data from the new node formed and it printed the full list out

Comment: There are mistakes in other parts that have not been pointed out yet. Good luck.

Comment: Are you working on a platform where [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is available?  If so, use it.  It will report where your code is abusing memory very succinctly. (Remember to compile with debugging enabled.  On Unix, that means use the `-g` option both when compiling to object and when linking.)  You've identified where the crash occurs. As @BLUEPIXY says, you need to protect the loop from accessing the null pointer, so the `while` condition needs to be more like `while (current != NULL && strcmp(new->model, current->model) < 0) { … }`. Crashes are often associated with dereferencing NULL.

Comment: I think you'll still need to deal with null pointers (`previous == NULL`) after the loop before you test `previous->next`.  At least, you should convince yourself that you can't suffer as a result of accessing a null pointer then.

Comment: When you write code, develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. In this case, get the sorted-order insertion working with a list of `int` before you attempt it with such complicated cargo.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your function `insertInSortedOrder()` and reading the warning of @JonathanLeffler, I have localized the problem of missing items in your sorted list.

> **Error** in the case of '*new is greater than current*'

- Unconditional overwrite of the `previous` pointer

Using the code `previous = new;` without checking if previous is pointing to a node will directly overwrite a part of the list by the new item.

- Not changing `head` when `previous == NULL`

When `previous == NULL`, the `new` item shall replace the `head`.

Use the following code:

```
if (previous==NULL) {
    // new becomes the first node
    new->next = head;
    head = new;
}
else {
    // new is inserted between previous and current
    new->next = previous->next;
    previous->next = new;
}
```

Instead of the code:

```
previous = newitem;
previous->next = current;
```

Comment: And a simpler form uses a pointer-to-pointer, needs only one variable and counts ~5 lines of code.